# Checkstyle not updating on save as it should [java]

Tags: java

I am using an xml file provided by my school to perform my checkstyle. I believe I have implemented everything properly, and I see checkstyle errors in my code, but when I correct an error and save the file, the error is still there, completely unchanged. For example, some errors say I need a javadoc, and even after I add the javadoc the error still says "Missing javadoc". I checked that my workspace is equipped to build automatically, so can anyone suggest why this may be occuring?

Comment: Is this link useful in your case: [Using Checkstyle Vogella](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/Checkstyle/article.html)

Comment: Which IDE are you using?